# How to refer to font file in Java Class

Tags: java, jsf, fonts, pdf-generation, itext

I need your help in referring to a font file which is called "arial.ttf" which is placed under the below path:

> resources/fonts/arial.ttf

in my Java web application. The application is built in JSF. I am using iText to generate the PDF files and in the Java classed I am using the below code to state the font:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
```

This is working fine in my local environment, however, now I want to deploy the application and I need to remove the reference to my local drive c:/, therefore, followed how JSF is referring to an image or any file which is:

```
<h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/XX_XX.gif" />
```

And I changed the path to:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("/resources/fonts/arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
```

But, unfortunately I got the below error:

> java.io.IOException: resources/fonts/arial.ttf not found as file or
>   resource.

Then also I tried to changed the path to :

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("\\resources\\fonts\\arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
```

But still it didn't get the file. So how can I refer to it.

Comment: But the resources directory is the resources directory of a Maven structure?, or it isn't related to Maven?

Comment: Why sometimes you reference the file c:\\windows\\fonts\\arial.ttf" and other times resources\\fonts\\arial.ttf?

Comment: JSF is referencing resources because they are within the web app... but your fonts are outside the web app, I guess... or where they are?